# How can I copy the order of one array into another? [Python]

Tags: python

I want to match the order of the values of one array to another.
For example, I have A and B:

```
A = [239  1678  2678  4430  199]
```

Order A:

> A5 < A1 < A2 < A3 < A4

Now my B list is:

```
B = [ 4126.77552299  984.39685939  237.92397237  497.72447701  3377.17916825]
```

Order B:

> B3 < B4 < B2 < B5 < B1

I want B to be in the same order than A, like this:

```
B = [ 497.72447701  984.39685939  3377.17916825  4126.77552299  237.92397237]
```

Order B:

> B5 < B1 < B2 < B3 < B4

A and B are examples, in my case I have a lot of tuples of vectors with a lot of different sizes. I need a general expresion to order one vector in function of another.

How can I do it?

Comment: keep values from A and B in one list.

Comment: What do you mean by `Array`. This doesn't look like python. If you want python lists, you have to use `,` between each item. `[ 239, 1678, 2678, 4430, 199]`

Comment: You need to get the permutation of the first array (may be by sorting it and examine how values are permuted), and then sort the second and apply the permutation to it.

Comment: @zorro, Can it be that you have an slight error in your question? You state that B5 should be the first element, but  that would be "3377.17916825" and not "497.72447701" - as it is stated now.

Comment: @miku: No, it's not saying that B5 should be the first element. It's saying that the new B5 should be less than the new B1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We sort B in regular sorted order:

```
sorted_B = sorted(B)
```

Find where each element of `sorted_B` should go:

```
locations = sorted(range(len(A)), key=A.__getitem__)
```

And place those elements where they need to go in the result:

```
result = [None]*len(B)
for i, elem in zip(locations, sorted_B):
    result[i] = elem
```

Here's a [link](http://ideone.com/jQ92rp) to a demo showing that this produces the correct output for your example.

If you want to fill the results back into `B` directly instead of a copy, you can do that:

```
sorted_B = sorted(B)
locations = sorted(range(len(A)), key=A.__getitem__)
for i, elem in zip(locations, sorted_B):
    B[i] = elem
```

---

If you're working in NumPy and these are NumPy arrays, rather than lists, we should do the job with NumPy operations:

```
sorted_B = numpy.sort(B)
locations = numpy.argsort(A)
result = numpy.empty_like(B)
result[locations] = sorted_B
```

or in fewer lines:

```
result = numpy.empty_like(B)
result[numpy.argsort(A)] = numpy.sort(B)
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/6LCT33)

Or if you want to fill the results into `B` instead of a copy:

```
B[np.argsort(A)] = np.sort(B)
```

Comment: Since they want `B` itself to become sorted like that, how about `B[np.argsort(A)] = np.sort(B)`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Oh, huh, you're right. With or without NumPy, it's straightforward to write the result back into B instead of a copy.

Answer (score 2):

You may create a temporary dict to map the index of sorted list with the order. Then use the temporary dict to get the needed result as:

```
>>> A = [ 239, 1678, 2678, 4430, 199]
>>> B = [4126.77552299, 984.39685939, 237.92397237, 497.72447701, 3377.17916825]

# Temporary dict for mapping the `index` key with order as `value`
>>> order = {A.index(j): i  for i, j in enumerate(sorted(A))}
>>> order
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 0}

>>> sorted_B = sorted(B)  # sorted `B` list
>>> ordered_B = [sorted_B[order[i]] for i in range(len(B))]
>>> ordered_B  # desired output
[497.72447701, 984.39685939, 3377.17916825, 4126.77552299, 237.92397237]
```

Comment: Those `index` calls make this answer take quadratic time. It should be possible to eliminate them by using `enumerate` to associate items with indices before you sort.

Comment: (Sorry to post here.) I think your question edit changed the question, now it's not about NumPy anymore ("array" is a typical NumPy term and the odd spacing in the OP's original text matches exactly what I get when using and printing NumPy arrays).

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sorry, I am not familiar with numpy so I missed the context. Is it ok now? Please feel free to re-edit if I missed something :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Also please add the `numpy` tag if it is that relevant here

Comment: @user2357112 You are right. I haven't focussed that much on optimizing it. Let me see how I can do that

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Well at least it's as broken as originally :-). While I do think it's supposed to be NumPy, I'm not sure about it, so it's the OP who should say so (and provide proper code) if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it. Using `sorted` with the `key` argument to use any key function you want.

```
from operator import itemgetter
A = [239, 1678, 2678, 4430, 199]
B = [4126.77552299, 984.39685939, 237.92397237, 497.72447701, 3377.17916825]

# first get the order of list A
order, _ = zip(*sorted(enumerate(A), key=itemgetter(1)))
# then use that order to sort the other list
[n[0] for n in sorted(zip(sorted(B), order), key=itemgetter(1))]

[497.72447701, 984.39685939, 3377.17916825, 4126.77552299, 237.92397237]
```

Instead of `itemgetter(1)`, you could use this lambda `key=lambda x: x[1]`

Edit: As @mkrieger pointed out, you don't actually need a key function if you sort a list of tuples, if you put the key value as the first element in the tuple.
`zip(A, range(len(A)))` is similar to enumerate, but with the indices and items swapped.

So this would also get the same result, with a bit simpler code, since you don't need the key functions, and no imports are needed either.

```
order = [i for _, i in sorted(zip(A, range(len(A))))]  
B = [b for _, b in sorted(zip(order, sorted(B)))]
```

demo: http://ideone.com/zCXOHu

Comment: The final step can be simplified to `[n[1] for n in sorted(zip(order, sorted(B)))]`, or better yet `[n for _, n in sorted(zip(order, sorted(B)))]`.

Comment: You are right, I've added your suggestion to my answer.